# Data from form going directly into MailChimp list

Tags: database, forms, mailchimp

I've been looking for an answer to this. I have a website I work on with a sign up form, and I would like the data entered to go directly into a MailChimp 'database.' The only thing I can find info on is how to link MailChimp list to a database, but I don't need a second database right now. If I could just get the values entered into the mailchimp list that would be groovy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some more information about your installation would be helpful. For example, I know of an excellent plugin for Wordpress.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp/

Otherwise, it sounds like you may need to sign up for an API key.

http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/

http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/downloads/mcapi-simple-subscribe-jquery.zip

Comment: I believe we already have a key. The form isn't within a wp installation, it's coded in html and processed with a php file. There is a section of the website that has a wp blog and I did consider moving the sign up form there and just use plugins, but I would rather just learn how to do this.

Comment: Here's the url www.umvaonline.org

Comment: do I just add the api 'language' right into my form processing file?

Comment: Here's another example that might be easier to implement.

https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api/

Comment: Ok, I'm going to use drewm mailchimp api. Looks easy enough. Thanks!

Comment: Now how do I get it to sort the list after a new subscriber using the api? In php if possible.